# List Converted Web Applications in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a number of web applications that sit under the Default Web Site in IIS.
I want to use PowerShell to list all of these applications.

I've tried the below to list everything under Default Web Site, but it shows me every file and folder whereas I only want to see the folders that have been converted to applications.

```
dir IIS:\Sites\'Default Web Site' | select name
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Get-WebApplication`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790554.aspx):

```
Get-WebApplication -Site 'Default Web Site' | select Name
```

Comment: Thanks but a bunch of empty rows are returned if I do this. It's like it's loading the records but with no values if that makes sense.

Comment: Try to remove the `| select Name` part, the property might have another name (like `SiteName` or something). you can pipe the results to `| Get-Member` to check it out

Comment: This did the trick Get-WebApplication -Site 'Default Web Site' | select path